# Cifrar mensajes via JavaScript

Tags: nodejs, socket.io

estoy aprendiendo a usar Node.js, Sockets, y un poco de criptografía,mi idea es hacer un chat en local, donde los mensajes se cifren y descifren , la cosa es que soy incapaz de hacer que se descifren, he conseguido hacer que se envien los mensajes por el chat pero cifrados, pero no se como hacer para descifrarlos, haber si me podeis ayudar,gracias.

```javascript
var username = prompt('Dime tu username, por favor'); socket.emit('username', username);
var crypt = new JSEncrypt({ default_key_size: 200 });
crypt.getKey(function () {
    var publicKey = crypt.getPublicKey();
    var privateKey = crypt.getPrivateKey();
    console.log("Clave pública generada:", publicKey);
    console.log("Clave privada generada:", privateKey);
});

socket.on('public_key', function(publicKey) {
    crypt.setPublicKey(publicKey);
    console.log("Clave pública del servidor recibida y configurada:", publicKey);
});

socket.on('is_online', function(username) {
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(username));
});

$('#chatForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const plaintext = $('#txt').val();
    const encryptedMessage = crypt.encrypt(plaintext);

    socket.emit('chat_message', encryptedMessage);
    $('#txt').val('');

    return false;
});

socket.on('chat_message', function(encryptedChunk) {
    console.log("Mensaje cifrado:", encryptedChunk);

    const sender = encryptedChunk.username;
    const encryptedMessage = encryptedChunk.message.encryptedMessage;
    const symKey = encryptedChunk.message.symKey;
    const iv = encryptedChunk.message.iv;

  
    const decryptedMessage = decryptMessage(encryptedMessage, symKey, iv);
    console.log("Mensaje descifrado:", decryptedMessage);

    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(`<strong>${sender}:</strong> ${decryptedMessage}`));
});
function decryptMessage(encryptedMessage, symKey, iv) {
  const key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(symKey);
  const initializationVector = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(iv);
  const decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
    {
      ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(encryptedMessage) 
    },
    key,
    { iv: initializationVector }
  );
  return decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Este es el cliente

```javascript
io.sockets.on(
  "connection",
  function (socket) {
    socket.on("username",
      function (username) {
        socket.username = username;
        socket.on(
          'public_key',
          function (publicKey) {
            io.emit('public_key', publicKey);
          }
        );
        io.emit(
          "is_online",
          " <i>" + socket.username + " se une al chat...</i>"
        );
      }
    );

    socket.on(
      "disconnect",
      function () {
        io.emit("is_online", " <i> " + socket.username + " ha dejado el chat...</i>");
      }
    );

    socket.on(
      'chat_message',
      function (encryptedMessage) {
        io.emit('chat_message', {
          username: socket.username,
          message: encryptMessage(encryptedMessage)
        });
      });
  });
function encryptMessage(plaintext) {
  const symKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', symKey, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return { encryptedMessage: encrypted, symKey: symKey.toString('hex'), iv: iv.toString('hex') };
}
```

Y este el servidor, adjunto imagen de mi problema

[image: Esto es el chat]